# Why can't I install Tkinter in Python on Kubuntu 18.06

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pip

I am having this problem for 2 days and can't find the answer of the problem. I installed Python version 3.9.5 on Ubuntu. I went to install Tkinter on new Python version and my pip installation was linked to wrong version of python. When I typed "pip --version" it displayed 2.7, and when I typed with pip3 it displayed version 3.6. Even when I tried to install tkinter on Python 3.6, it didn't work, didnt want to install nor import.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Tkinter
```

I checked installed modules in pip and pip3, there was not Tkinter. Shouldn't it be installed already with Python?

Comment: Tkinter can't be installed with Pip. Try `apt search tkinter` to see if there's a related system level package you can install.

Comment: This is what i got back: python3.9-tk/bionic 3.9.5-1+bionic1 amd64
  Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python (version 3.9)

python3.9-tk-dbg/bionic 3.9.5-1+bionic1 amd64
  Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python (version 3.9 debug extension)

Comment: So... Maybe install that python 3.9 and its tk?

Comment: But how do I do it? I typed "sudo apt-get install python3.9-tk" and it did nothing

Comment: try to import tkinter in the python `repl`

Comment: No module named "Tkinter"

Comment: Should be `tkinter` instead of `Tkinter` for Python 3.